# Could the flags tool be expanded into a flags review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags

It seems like the flags tool could really benefit by being converted to a review queue in the new panel, still only being available to users with 10,000 reputation.

**Benefits:**

- I don't have to sit there and expand every flag I attempt to review, then expand again to view the comments. So much clicking!
- I'll have some useful stats about the post off to the right to help me in my judgement.
- Questions flagged as duplicates would have nice additional tabs to quickly view the proposed duplicate, similar to the close queue.
- I don't have to click on "Tools" or "Review" as much to switch back and forth between them. Seriously, this is pretty much the only time I ever go into the Tools section, personally.

**Buttons:**

- Flag
- Disagree (automatically cast my "invalid flag" flag)
- Edit
- Close (on questions)
- Delete (if allowed to do so)
- Skip

Comment: This is unlikely to be useful outside of SO.